# No sound in the Android Studio emulator on MSI P65 with Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: command-line, sound, pulseaudio, android-emulator

I have an MSI P65 with Ubuntu 19.10 distro. My emulator in Android Studio has no sound. The event log of Android Studio shows these warnings/errors:

```
18:41   Emulator: Fontconfig error:
"/home/fabrizio/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf", line 10: junk after
document element

18:41   Emulator: pulseaudio: pa_context_connect() failed

18:41   Emulator: pulseaudio: Reason: Connection refused

18:41   Emulator: pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextaudio:
Could not init `pa' audio driver
```

If i use the command `pulseaudio` in terminal I get these errors:

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.  
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

Already tried to delete the files in `.config/pulse` but it didn't work.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 3):

There is a "/" missing, otherwise its a relative link. There you go ...

```
sudo ln -s /run/user/1000/pulse/native /run/user/1000/snap.android-studio/pulse/
```

Comment: THANK YOU. You solved my problem with a command line.

Comment: This worked in 20.04 too.

Comment: Tha command broke my ubuntu 20.04 VM and now I cant boot it. Dont use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command, just as it is without changing anything.

```
sudo ln -s run/user/1000/pulse/native /run/user/1000/snap.android-studio/pulse/
```

For the canary:

```
sudo ln -s /run/user/1000/pulse/native /run/user/1000/snap.android-studio-canary/pulse/
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked to me. With Android Studio Snap on Manjaro.

Answer (score 1):

The symbolic link solutions mentioned in the other answers only works until reboot for me.

However, the solution provided in [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62088518) by [Mo'ath Hasan Alshorman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3475806/moath-hasan-alshorman) works for me in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with snap Android Studio even after reboot:

> The solution is by installing ***paprefs*** small app as follows.
>
> 1. Install it:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install paprefs
>    ```
> 2. Open it:
>
>    ```
>    paprefs
>    ```
> 3. Go to the last tab Simultaneous Output and click on the only option there in order to enable the Simultaneous Output.
>
> [image: PulseAudio preferences dialog]
>
> 4. Restart it:
>
>    ```
>    pulseaudio -k
>    ```
> 5. If it fails then you have to restart the daemon
>
>    ```
>    pulseaudio -D
>    ```
> 6. Almost finished, go to the system settings and navigate to Sounds options and change the output sounds to the newly added one as below.
>
> [image: output device settings in sound settings]

Answer (score 1):

Same problem in Ubuntu 20.04, tried everything here and other solutions, no luck. What worked for me is to uninstall Android Studio from Ubuntu Software, and reinstall downloaded from Android Studio website.

https://developer.android.com/studio

Answer (score 1):

Launching the emulator manually I resolved ! (Ubuntu 20.04)

emulator program can be found inside android-sdk/tools/

To get le name of your device:

```
 ~/Android/Sdk/emulator -list-avds
```

To start the emulator with Sound !

```
 ~/Android/Sdk/emulator -avd @Nexus_5X_API_27
```